# My node.js doesn't respond without reporting any errors

Tags: node.js

I wrote http server in node.js, which is a like reverse-proxy for Amazon S3, and deployed it in production environment with Node's Cluster module, nodejitsu/forever and Nginx.
It worked very good but one day (today) it stopped responding. I checked node's console.log() outputs and processes but I found nothing strange.

Gist of my code is like:

```
http.createServer(function(webReq, webRes) {
  http.get(s3Options, function(s3Res) {
    if (s3Res.statusCode == 200) {
      s3Res.on('end', function() {
        webRes.end('Found data on S3');
      });
    } else {
      webRes.end('No data on S3'); 
    }
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with s3Req: ' + e.message);
  });
}).listen(1337);
```

Node processes are all alive (2 child workers) without forever's restarting:

```
# ps x | grep node
31436 ?  Ss  3:43 node /usr/bin/forever -l LOG -o OUT -e ERR -a start server.js
31437 ?  Sl  0:10 node /root/server.js
31440 ?  Sl  1:17 /usr/bin/nodejs /root/server.js
31441 ?  Sl  1:17 /usr/bin/nodejs /root/server.js
```

Then I doubted too-many-connection stuffs and did "lsof -p PID | wc -l" but the counts were all in good conditions - only dozens.

My node.js experience is only a week or so. Did I miss something important?

Comment: My concern is not the reason why my node server doesn't respond but why it doesn't output any errors.

Comment: Tested your code locally (with a request to `google.com`, since I don't have the contents of `s3Options`) and it works as expected (gives `Found data on S3`). The issue appears to be specific to your actual `s3Options` request.

Comment: Thank you, lanzz. 
var s3Options = {
  host:   '*****.s3.amazonaws.com',
  port:   80,
  path:   webReq.url,
  method: 'GET',
};
But this has worked well until today. Should I add timeout param?

Comment: So you are logging other messages?  When you say the server isn't responding, do you mean a request to 1337 times out?

Comment: Matthew, yes, I was logging other messages and every things were ok until the server stopped. When opening http://xxx:1337, my browser kept loading and didn't stop. Then I restarted forever it started to work well again. But I'm still afraid the same thing will happen again.